# Update nested React state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to update part of a state object that is nested. This is the object:

```
const [buttonObject, setButtonObject] = useState({
    intro: [
      {
        id: '123',
        name: 'first_intro_name',
        selected: false,
      },
      {
        id: '124',
        name: 'second_intro_name',
        selected: false,
      },
    ],
    experience: [
      {
        id: '789',
        name: 'first_experience_name',
        selected: false,
      },
      {
        id: '8910',
        name: 'second_experience_name',
        selected: false,
      },
    ],
  });
```

When a button is clicked I want to toggle the selected state. I'm using a click handler that looks like this:

```
const handleButtonClick = ({ id, selected }) => {
    if (id === '123') {
      buttonsObject.intro.map(
        pref => (pref.selected = pref.id === id ? !pref.selected : selected)
      );
      setButtonsObject(buttonsObject);
    } else if (id === '124') {
      buttonsObject.intro.map(
        pref => (pref.selected = pref.id === id ? !pref.selected : selected)
      );
      setButtonsObject(buttonsObject);
    }
  };
```

It would handle experiences as well. The issue is that right now it seems like rather than updating the object it just overwrites the object or creates a new one. It also doesnt pass that information back down to the component even though I have it routed correctly so it should.

Is there better/correct syntax for updating nested state like this?

Thanks.

Comment: `buttonsObject.intro.map(...)` just returns a new array, it doesn't modify anything on the existing array. You _are_ however modifying the **objects** within that array, which you should not do (as you are seeing, those changes don't trigger re-renders). This is partly why nested state objects are hard to work with - keeping things immutable becomes a pain. I'd recommend [passing a function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) to your `setButtonsObject()` call, and using the previous object to create a new one, complete with the newly mapped `intro` arrays.

Answer (score 0):

instead of checking again with if condition use higher order array function and spread operator to get optimal solution.

```js
setButtonObject(previous => {

    return {
        ...previous,
        info: previous.info.map(item => item.id === id ? {
            ...item,
            selected: true
        } ? item)

    }

})
```

Comment: Those are ternaries right? Don't we need : to complete them?